# JavaScript multiply two ids

Tags: javascript

I am trying to multiply two values that script get from below two different api. I am using document.getelementbyid to get the two id that I need which is gbp and balance. The api script can display the data get from api. However, the multiply script is not working. Nothing is showing. Help please?

first api

```
 $(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=ETH,GBP,HKD",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(typeof data); 
        var json = data;
        $('#gbp').html(json.GBP);
        $('#hkd').html(json.HKD);
    }
    });
    });
```

second api

```
$(function() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/reportedhashrate/1",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    console.log(typeof data); // -- Object
    var json = data;
    $('#balance').html(json.data);
}
});
});
```

multiply javascript:

```
 $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var $butbut =document.getElementById('gbp').html;
        var $siksik =document.getElementById('balance').html;
        var $lamlam =  $butbut * $siksik;
        document.getElementById('money').html=$lamlam;
    });
```

html script

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Untitled-4.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="balance"></div>

    <div id="money"></div>
    <div id="gbp"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Replace `.html` with `.innerHTML` if you open your browser console you will be able to see error reports to help you while using `javascript`.

Comment: You need to use `.innerHTML` instead. 
You'll probably get an error saying `.html` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the inner html of an element is `.innerHTML`, not `.html`

```
var $butbut = document.getElementById('gbp').innerHTML;
var $siksik = document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = $lamlam;
```

Alternatively, you can use jquery

```
var $butbut = $('#gpb').html();
var $siksik = $('#balance').html();
$('#money').html($lamlam);
```

Comment: A mistype but you are missing a single quote on your selector. `$('#money')`

Comment: How about the multiply part? I change all the .html to .innerHTML and now only zero appear.

Comment: Are there values in those `div` elements to actually multiply?  If so, you might have to make sure each value is a `integer` or `float` depending on the data you're expecting.  For example, either `parseInt($butbut) * parseInt($siksik)` or `parseFloat($butbut) * parseFloat($siksik)`

Comment: @snapjs  I tried to use parsefloat and parseInt and both of them result  are NaN. Those div elements are numbers for example 0 and 250.

Comment: @yoona1314 Are you making sure to do this within the `success` callback of your AJAX call?  Otherwise the data might not be populated yet.

Comment: @snapjs Yes I just check both of the api returns success. The div class was able to display the correct information,`<div id="balance"></div> and
  <div id="gbp"></div>` are displaying the correct numbers.

Comment: @yoona1314 I'm not sure I'm communicating correctly: What I'm suggesting is you should do the multiplication within the `success: function (data) { }` callback function

Comment: @snapjs but the data are from different api. Which one should I do the multiplication within the callback function?

Comment: @yoona1314 You could have a global variable that you increment after each successful return, and call the addition function on each return.  If the global variable equals to total number of expected callbacks, execute the function